# Can you train GPT-J to use a specific list of words and prioritise them?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, gpt, natural-language-generation, gpt-3

Can you train GPT-J to use a specific list of words and prioritise them? If so, please could you share how I would go about this?

Say you're using GPT-J to write a story, you might wish to mention certain key terms more than others, or in a specific order.

Comment: You might even be able to do it without training, just by artificially raising the probabilities of those words in the output. Models like GPT-J don't output words, they output probabilities of words.